# Which CSS prefix for transition is correct "-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.0"s or "-webkit-transition: transform 1.0s"

Tags: css, webkit, transition, prefix

When I use the -webkit prefix for my transition, will it's opacity value also need a -webkit prefix? So:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
```

or

```
-webkit-transition: transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
```

Comment: The second is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! In this case opacity was only an example, transform eg needs a prefix for "-webkit" and "-ms". Or are there no prefixes in the transition property at all?

Comment: Some properties still require prefixing, some don't. It's worthwhile looking into prefixing solutions such as [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or [**PrefixFree**](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to do this for you,

Answer (score 0):

I ran the CSS code

```
transition: transform 0.4s;
```

through the autoprfixer https://autoprefixer.github.io/ (since I don't want to implement autoprefixer on my Website). This is the (supposedly right) result:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
```